# Add a column with Ticker after converting zoo to dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, xts, lapply, quantmod

I am trying to add a column after I had converted a xts to a dataframe as xts can only include numeric values.  Additional I want to bind them by row as a final result, but I fail and don´t find the solution. Here is my code which is collected from different authors on stackoverflow. Thanks to that!

```
library(quantmod)

# Fetch all Symbols from AMEX
symbols <- stockSymbols(exchange = c("AMEX"))  
symbols <- symbols[,1]  

# define environment
data <- new.env()

# Load Stock data in environment
getSymbols(symbols,from="2016-01-01", env=data)

# build function to convert zoo to dataframe
zoo.to.data.frame <- function(x, index.name="Date") {
     stopifnot(is.zoo(x))
     xn <- if(is.null(dim(x))) deparse(substitute(x)) else colnames(x)
     setNames(data.frame(index(x), x, row.names=NULL), c(index.name,xn))
}

# build function to calculate different signals (...only price and ADX in this example)
"SignalCalculator" <- function(x) {
      # Adjusted Price
       price <- x[,c(6)]

      # ADX
      adx <- ADX(x[,c("High","Low","Close")], n =14)
      DIp <- adx$DIp
      DIn <- adx$DIn
      Adx <- adx$ADX

      # bind single values together and convert to dataframe
      result  <- zoo.to.data.frame(cbind(price, DIp, DIn, Adx))
      # the following is not working respectively I don´t know how to
      # result2 <- cbind(result, Ticker = x) 
}

# Loop function on data #
lapply(data,FUN = SignalCalculator)
```

What I would like to do after the function is applied to all the ticker, is to generate one huge dataframe with a row bind, with all the tickers inside to export them to a csv file. This should look like the following. But for me it is unclear how to bind them together? I appreciate any help on this topic. Thanks.

[Table with stock data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpFgI.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`out2` below is in the format of the table in the link you provided.  You can make use of helper functions from `xts`, like `HLC` and `Ad` which are more flexible than hard coding your column selections, and you don't need to do that `zoo.to.data.frame` stuff.

```
# define environment
data <- new.env()

# Load Stock data in environment
getSymbols(symbols,from="2016-01-01", env=data)

SignalCalculator2 <- function(x) {
    # Assumes first colname format is still [tickername].Open
    tickername <- strsplit(colnames(x)[1], "\\.")[[1]][1]
    # Adjusted Price:
    price <- Ad(x)
    colnames(price) <- "Price"
    adx <- ADX(HLC(x), n = 14)
    # You dont want this column in your table:
    adx$DX <- NULL
    res <- merge(price, adx)
    # res is an xts object.  Now convert to data.frame
    df_res <- data.frame("Date" = index(res), "Ticker" = tickername, coredata(res))
    df_res
}

# data is an environment, not a list, so can use eapply (similar to lapply):
out <- eapply(env = data, FUN = SignalCalculator2)
out2 <- do.call(rbind, out)
# If you want to order rows by date:
out2 <- out2[order(out2$Date),]
# Optional tidy up:
rownames(out2) <- NULL


> tail(out2)
# Date Ticker Price      DIp      DIn      ADX
# 164 2016-08-25   AAMC 12.72 17.67766 21.28021 11.31483
# 330 2016-08-25    AAU  1.42 22.36896 23.64023 30.50243
# 165 2016-08-26   AAMC 12.80 16.48608 21.07136 11.37868
# 331 2016-08-26    AAU  1.36 23.02102 21.80518 28.51742
# 166 2016-08-29   AAMC 13.15 15.75814 20.14096 11.43797
# 332 2016-08-29    AAU  1.43 21.63012 22.30030 26.58943
```

Comment: Great! That is how it should look like. Thank you for simplifying my code too! Just one question. Is it possible  to select only the last date for each ticker?

Comment: Sure. Assuming the last date could be different for each ticker, an easy approach:  `library(data.table); dt_out <- as.data.table(out2);  dt_out[Date == max(Date),.SD,by = list(Ticker)];`

Comment: Ok. This looks good. When i run the code, it shows me the results how it should be in the console. But when i run `View(dt_out)` I get all dates as before?

Comment: `res <- dt_out[Date == max(Date),.SD,by = list(Ticker)]; print(res)`